# Css float resizing layout

Tags: css, layout, resize, css-float

I have problem with CSS on my school project blog. I have two columns, left and right in container with max-width to aim automatic resizing. 
However it´s not working correctly. 
On some specific width the left column with articles jumps under the right column and it starts resizing only when it come to the edge of text.
My aim is to resize it to preserve the left column next to right.

As you are not able to view my blog without login here I created fiddle for deomnstration and this is the important part of css.

```
#content{
max-width:65em;
margin:0 auto;}

#left-column{
float:left;
max-width:44em;
}

#right-column{
max-width:19em;
float:right;
margin-left:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Nbu2/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try giving them both a css float to the left. 
Using fixed pixel size's and adding a clearfix - explained here http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float on the left-column.

Comment: Your answer may be better with some explanations

Comment: its working however border bottom under article exceeds to right column :/

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to .article